# How do I iterate through an array and change characters efficiently?

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, iteration

I currently have this method in my work for a Ruby assignment where I need to change the vowels and consonants in a name put in by a user, to the next successive vowel/consonant, so ( a = e, e = i, etc.) and the same process for the consonants ( b = c, d = f, etc.). I did it the 'easy' way, but now I need to change it so that instead, I am iterating through an array and changing the vowels/consonants that way.

I am new to iteration so I am having trouble with this.

Here is my original method:

```
puts "What is your full name?"
full_name = gets.chomp 

def vowelreplace(full_name)
 vowels = 'aeiou'
 replacements = 'eioua'
 full_name.tr(vowels, replacements)
end

name_next_vowel = vowelreplace(full_name)

p name_next_vowel

def consonantreplace(name_next_vowel)
  consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'
  replacements = 'cdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzb'
  name_next_vowel.tr(consonants, replacements)
end

new_spyname = consonantreplace(name_next_vowel)

p new_spyname
```

Here's what I've started working with to change it below using an array and block method. Is there an easier less lengthy way of doing this? Is there a .next way of doing this, or in general, a more efficient way?

```
puts "What is your first name?"
first_name = gets.chomp 

arr = first_name.split("") 

p arr 

arr.map! { |element|
  if(element == "a")
    "e" 
  elsif(element == "e")
    "i"
  elsif(element == "i")
    "o"
  elsif(element == "o")
    "u"
  elsif(element == "u")
    "a"
  else
    element
  end
 }

p arr

new_arr = arr

new_arr.map! { |element|
  if(element == "b")
    "c" 
  elsif(element == "c")
    "d"
  elsif(element == "d")
    "f"
  elsif(element == "f")
    "g"
  elsif(element == "g")
    "h"
  elsif(element == "h")
    "j"
  elsif(element == "j")
    "k"
  elsif(element == "k")
    "l"
  elsif(element == "l")
    "m"
  elsif(element == "m")
    "n"
  elsif(element == "n")
    "p"
  elsif(element == "p")
    "q"
  elsif(element == "q")
    "r"
  elsif(element == "r")
    "s"
  elsif(element == "s")
    "t"
  elsif(element == "t")
    "v"
  elsif(element == "v")
    "w"
  elsif(element == "w")
    "x"
  elsif(element == "x")
    "y"
  elsif(element == "y")
    "z"
  elsif(element == "z")
    "b"
  else
     element
  end
 }

p new_arr 

arr.join("")
```

Comment: Since this is an assignment I'm hesitant to give a complete solution. 

First, you could easily use the `tr` method like you originally did, but do so for each character within your `map` (iterator) block.

Another possibility is to create a mapping between the original characters and what they should be transformed to. "a" => "e", "b" => "c", etc. That is just Hash notation! You could each character to easily look up the next value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the `tr` approach, but if you want something similar to `next`, then [`Array#rotate`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-rotate) could be a good option; here's an example:

```
def letter_swap(full_name)
  vowels     = %w(a e i o u)
  consonants = %w(b c d f g h j k l m n p q r s t v w x y z)

  full_name.each_char.with_object("") do |char, new_name|
    if vowels.include?(char)
      new_name << vowels.rotate(vowels.index(char) + 1).first
    elsif consonants.include?(char)
      new_name << consonants.rotate(consonants.index(char) + 1).first
    else
      new_name << char
    end
  end
end
```

Of course you could DRY this code, but at the expense of readability (IMO); for example:

```
def letter_swap(full_name)
  letters = [%w(a e i o u), %w(b c d f g h j k l m n p q r s t v w x y z)]

  full_name.each_char.with_object("") do |char, new_name|
    group = letters.find { |group| group.include?(char) }
    new_name << (group.nil? ? char : group.rotate(group.index(char) + 1).first)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I really like the first method for it's readability... it makes sense. I haven't used the rotate method yet, this is great!

Comment: @BrittFlowers Glad to help! :) Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted (this, or the one you find most helpful) by clicking the tick on the left.

Comment: thanks for the heads up! I'm a stack overflow newbie, so I appreciate the tips :)

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe use a series of case statements inside of your map loop instead?

```
arr.map! { |element|
  case element
    when "a" then "e"
    when "e" then "i"
    when "i" then "o"
    when "o" then "u"
    when "u" then "a"
  end
}
```

Same would go for the consonants as well..

Comment: Thanks so much! Wow, that is a MUCH easier way, awesome!

Comment: You're welcome! I'd really appreciate an upvote if you feel that my answer was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [String#tr](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-tr) with an array of characters much as you would with a string, but `tr` has time complexity O(n), since characters of the first argument are examined sequentially when attempting to find a match. If a number of such lookups are to be made it would be much faster to use a hash, which has a nearly-constant lookup time. You might write a method as follows.

**Code**

```
VOWELS = %w|a e i o u|
  #=> ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
NEXT_VOWEL = VOWELS.zip(VOWELS.rotate(1)).to_h
  #=> {"a"=>"e", "e"=>"i", "i"=>"o", "o"=>"u", "u"=>"a"}
CONSONANTS = ('a'..'z').to_a - VOWELS
  #=> ["b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n",
  #    "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
NEXT_CONSONANT = CONSONANTS.zip(CONSONANTS.rotate(1)).to_h
  #=> {"b"=>"c", "c"=>"d", "d"=>"f", "f"=>"g", "g"=>"h", "h"=>"j", "j"=>"k",
  #    "k"=>"l", "l"=>"m", "m"=>"n", "n"=>"p", "p"=>"q", "q"=>"r", "r"=>"s",
  #    "s"=>"t", "t"=>"v", "v"=>"w", "w"=>"x", "x"=>"y", "y"=>"z", "z"=>"b"}

def code(arr)
  arr.map { |c| NEXT_CONSONANT[c] || NEXT_VOWEL[c] || c }
end
```

Presumably, you would need to be able to decode as well. You could write the decode method as follows, making use of the method [Hash#invert](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-invert).

```
PREVIOUS_VOWEL = NEXT_VOWEL.invert
  # => {"e"=>"a", "i"=>"e", "o"=>"i", "u"=>"o", "a"=>"u"}
PREVIOUS_CONSONANT = NEXT_CONSONANT.invert
  #=> {"c"=>"b", "d"=>"c", "f"=>"d", "g"=>"f", "h"=>"g", "j"=>"h", "k"=>"j", "l"=>"k",
  #    "m"=>"l", "n"=>"m", "p"=>"n", "q"=>"p", "r"=>"q", "s"=>"r", "t"=>"s", "v"=>"t",
  #    "w"=>"v", "x"=>"w", "y"=>"x", "z"=>"y", "b"=>"z"}

def decode(arr)
  arr.map { |c| PREVIOUS_CONSONANT[c] || PREVIOUS_VOWEL[c] || c }
end
```

**Example**

First code the array.

```
arr = "billy-bob".chars
  #=> ["b", "i", "l", "l", "y", "-", "b", "o", "b"]
a = code(arr)
  #=> ["c", "o", "m", "m", "z", "-", "c", "u", "c"]
a.join
  #=> "commz-cuc"
```

Then decode it.

```
a = decode ["c", "o", "m", "m", "z", "-", "c", "u", "c"]
  #=> ["b", "i", "l", "l", "y", "-", "b", "o", "b"]
a.join
  #=> "billy-bob"
```

**Explanation**

Consider the expression

```
NEXT_CONSONANT[c] || NEXT_VOWEL[c] || c
```

in the method `code`. Suppose `c = 'd'`. Then `NEXT_COSONANT['d'] #=> 'f'`, so we have

```
'f' || NEXT_VOWEL[c] || c
```

Since `'f'` is truthy, `'f'` is returned. Ruby has no reason to evaluate `NEXT_VOWEL[c] || c` so she doesn't.

Now suppose `c = 'e'`. Then, since `NEXT_CONSONANT` has no key `'e'`, `NEXT_CONSONANT['e'] #=> nil` and the expression becomes

```
nil || NEXT_VOWEL[c] || c
```

It therefore is necessary to evaluate `NEXT_VOWEL['e']`. As that returns `'i'`, which is truthy, `'i'` is returned and there is no need to evaluate `c`.

Lastly, if `c = '-'`, we obtain

```
nil || nil || c
```

so `c` is evaluated and returned.